# Control group participants

Tags: experiment-design, control-group

I have read a lot especially on RCT design but this hasnt been explicitly answered anywhere. Does the control group participants have to have 'opted-in' to the intervention and failed/not been selected? I can match them otherwise with the treatment group due to common characteristics. Context: government stimulus grant provided to a set of farmers that applied for it. Can I survey the farmers who didnt apply for the grant or express interest as the control group?

Answer (score 2):

No, the randomisation is the point of an RCT.  Economic/development RCTs have been done when there are too many qualified applicants to a grant program and the ones who receive the grant are chosen *at random* from the qualified applicants. The ones not chosen at random are then controls, differing only in randomisation.

You could do an analysis where you don't have randomisation but attempt to match individuals who do and don't receive the intervention. That can be a reasonable study design, but it isn't an RCT.  For example, a matched analysis of this sort was recently published [for the Pfizer Covid vaccine](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa2101765), using data from vaccinated and not-yet-vaccinated people in Israel, with careful matching. It was much larger than any RCT, and so it provided valuable information, but it wasn't an RCT